# Array type in type script

Tags: typescript

Why is this allowed by TypeScript?
I specified a numeric index. Why can I use a string as an index?
Visual studio doesn't report an error.

```
interface StringArray {
    [index: number]: string;

}

var a: StringArray;
a = { "key": "val" };
var b = a["key"];
```

Comment: well, it is still Javascript, so it is valid as on any object you can access the property values like that

Answer (score 4):

**Problem**

It's because the compiler is still allowing implicit `any` types which can happen when accessing a property of an object by using an index:

```
// Example 1
let dictionary: { [index: number]: string };
let myStringTypedVar = dictionary[5];   // implicitly typed as "string"
let myAnyTypedVar = dictionary["prop"]; // implicitly typed as "any"

// Example 2
let myNumberTypedVar = 5;
let myAnyTypedVar = myNumberTypedVar["prop"]; // implicitly typed as "any"
```

**Fix: Compile with `--noImplictAny`**

If you compile your example with `--noImplictAny` then it will error:

```
tsc --noImplicitAny example.ts
```

Outputs:

> example.ts(8,9): error TS7017: Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type.

I would recommend always compiling with `--noImplicitAny`. In Visual Studio, you can turn on `--noImplictAny` by unchecking "Allow implicit 'any' types" in the project properties' typescript build tab:

[image: Disable allow implicit any]

Or by adding `"noImplicitAny": "true"` to `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json`.

Answer (score 2):

An array is also an objects. So you can access the object properties.

```
var array = [];
array.push("One"); // array
array[1]= "Two"; // array
array['key'] = "Three";// object
array.key2 = "Four"; // object
var length = array.length; // Is 2
```

Answer (score 1):

A numeric index signature only defines the type for properties accessed through a numeric index. It does not restrict property access to only a numeric index.

From the [TypeScript 1.5 specification](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf):

> **Numeric index signatures**, specified using index type number, define type constraints for all
>   numerically named properties in the containing type. Specifically, in a type with a numeric index
>   signature of type T, all numerically named properties must have types that are assignable to T

But, I think you have a good point. It does seem like properties should not be accessed by a string index if you have only defined a numeric index signature.