# TypeScript index signature in an object literal

Tags: typescript

I want my object's properties to be indexed by `number` only. This is the type that I have annotated my object with:

```
var obj: { [y: number]: string };
```

Here's how I tested:

```
obj = { x: '100', y: '20', z: 'abc', 0: 'def'}
obj['x'] = 'abcd'; // I expected TypeScript to throw an error because the property is indexed through a string, but it works fine
obj[0] = 'def'; // This works fine as I expected.
```

Did I miss anything fundamental here?

Comment: object properties name in javascript are strings

Comment: Then whats the use of [y:number] here?

Comment: This is kind of confusing but other people have already asked about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33626014/array-type-in-type-script